# How can I change a PDF's encoding using Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf

How to change pdf encoding using perl ? If possible, which module/method is used ?

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=793929.Module Used "PDF::EasyPDF". Also, see perldoc for Encoding http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html

Comment: Are you creating the PDF using Perl?  What module are you using?

Comment: @cjm: Good point.  Are you creating this PDF yourself, or is it from some 3rd party?

Comment: Why "-1"? whats wrong with this question ? or what is there for "-1" please justify if possible !

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy.

"Encoding" in PDF can mean any of several things you probably don't want to mess with.

PDF is not some XML markup where the whole thing is in one encoding.  Each font can (and often does) define its own (possibly customized) encoding that is used to determine which glyphs from that font are to be drawn given the bytes in the content stream.  Said font isn't required to also provide a means of going from glyphs to CHARACTERS.

A "glyph" is a bunch of squiggles in a particular configuration.  It is purely graphical

A "character" has a meaning, is part of an alphabet, etc.  It is purely logical.

So, I must ask: Why do you want to change your PDFs' encoding.  What's the goal?  Are you trying to get text out of your PDFs, failing, and think this might help?

Comment: Well, Im not craeting pdf file, am parsing an existing pdf file, this file has different fonts, e.g. description about man pages [where normal text & code snippet{commands,c++ code snippet} are in different fonts]. I'm able to parse normal plain text but not the code snippet. I want to change the encoding style of code snippet in the given pdf file. Plesae let me know, if there is anything wrong in my thaught process ? code snippet is not in graphical format, it has different fonts & encoding style. Either i want a module to parse code snippet also or to change the style of code snippet !

Comment: At the time of parsing code snippet in the PDF, am getting some special characers like #2$5 etc & not actual word [e.g. void main()].